# jpgraph stacked bar chart lower into bottom

Tags: php, bar-chart, jpgraph

Data almost exactly the same, but just minor increase in value in each record, however the bar seems got extended below the axis! when stack together... Does anyone has similar issue before?

Thank You

Before

[image]

After
[image]

Comment: Do you have a negative value in your data ?

Comment: @BojanT hum, thats an interesting thought! I am not sure how can I see it... sry, I am rather new to jpgraph, any hint on that? Thanks!

Comment: Well you have a data to plot those graphs like PHP arrays ? $datatoplot=(312,12,131,1222,21,-2); check those

Comment: So you did not code anything, where did you get this samples, what is a PHP code for this, revert back column name , DB is throwing an error hence no graph shown

Comment: @BojanT Thanks! I just verified all the words you told me, yes, they are exactly the trouble. You should post the negative value and such into answer, I will credit you thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned above and as a graph shows you have a negative number in last Unaccounted Hours array element.